# Choose a series of rows between two other rows that contain specific values or strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

**EDIT:**
If the number of occurrences of Keyword1 and Keyword2 does not match, then the solutions provided does not work. I have updated the dataframe and code below to reflect a similar mismatch.

**ORIGINAL POST:** 
I have a dataframe of strings and I am trying to choose all the rows between two specific string values [Keyword1 and Keyword2].

I am using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'C1', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C2','C3', 'D','C4', 'B', 'C5'])
df.columns = ['Col1']

Keyword1= 'B'
Keyword2= 'D'

#Filter and delete file mode deliveries
a=df.index[df['Col1'] == Keyword1].tolist()
b=df.index[df['Col1'] == Keyword2].tolist() 
b=np.add(b, 1).tolist() 
 

index=[]
for i in range(len(b)):
    index_temp=np.arange(a[i],b[i]).tolist()
    index=index+index_temp

df_keep= df[df.index.isin(index)]   
df_del= df[~df.index.isin(index)]
```

While this does the work, I am wondering if there a more efficient way to perform the same task.

Comment: Not sure why the first row is in `df_del` as it is not between the two keywords. Kindly see my answer.

Comment: In your new output, the values that don't make sense to me are: `1)` The first item -- it is not between `D` and `B`. It is the first item, so it cannot be between two items. `2)` why is the second to last item `B` outputted? We are outputting between `D` and `B`, so why is this `B` outputted? 3)  Likewise, why is the last item `C5` outputted and others are not? It is the last item and not between two items.

Comment: Think of 'B' as the starting string and 'D' as the ending string. The items that does fall under this category are: B, C1, D, B, C2, C3, D. These items go to df_keep and the rest go to df_del.

Answer (score 0):

This should be more efficient than looping. You can create series of conditions `c1` and `c2` that are boolean series based off `cumsum` logic and `idxmin` that essentially tell you if values are between `D` and `B`. Using `cumsum` helps you identify the change of value to `B` or `D` which helps you find values in between:

```
df['s'] = ((df['Col1'] == 'D') | (df['Col1'] == 'B')).cumsum()
c1 = (df.index != df.groupby('s')['s'].transform('idxmin'))
c2 = ((df['Col1'] == 'B').cumsum() == (df['Col1'] == 'D').cumsum())
df_del = df[c1 & c2].drop('s', axis=1)
df_del
Out[1]: 
  Col1
4    A
9   C4

df_keep = df[~(c1 & c2)].drop('s', axis=1)
df_keep
Out[2]: 
   Col1
0     A
1     B
2    C1
3     D
5     B
6    C2
7    C3
8     D
10    B
11   C5
12    D
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your solution. But the first 'A' has been missed as you correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Just another try:

```
ix1= np.where(df.Col1.eq('B'))[0]
ix2= np.where(df.Col1.eq('D'))[0]
df_keep = pd.concat([df.Col1.iloc[start:end+1] for start, end in zip(ix1,ix2)])
```

Prints:

```
1      B
2     C1
3      D
5      B
6     C2
7     C3
8      D
10     B
11    C5
12     D
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
df[((df.eq(Keyword2)*-1).shift().bfill() + df.eq(Keyword1)).cumsum().astype(bool)['Col1']]
```

Output:

```
   Col1
1     B
2    C1
3     D
5     B
6    C2
7    C3
8     D
10    B
11   C5
12    D
```

Use `eq` to assign 1 to keyword1 and -1 to keyword2 then use `cumsum` to find all places where value equals to 1 change it to True with `astype`, then boolean index the dataframe and dropna.

Details:

```
m1 = (df.eq(Keyword2)*-1).shift().bfill() #find the Keyword2
m1
```

Output:

```
    Col1
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4   -1.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8    0.0
9   -1.0
10   0.0
11   0.0
12   0.0
```

Nex,

```
m2 =  df.eq(Keyword1) #find the Keyword1
print(m2)
```

Ouput:

```
     Col1
0   False
1    True
2   False
3   False
4   False
5    True
6   False
7   False
8   False
9   False
10   True
11  False
12  False
```

And,

```
(m1 + m2).cumsum()

    Col1
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
8    1.0
9    0.0
10   1.0
11   1.0
12   1.0
```

Comment: This works as long as the occurrence of Keyword1 and Keyword2 are the same. If there is a mismatch, then it does not work.